# Can't get list of charges for customer

Tags: java, hashmap, stripe-payments

I’m doing charges according to this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers

1) Store customer:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("email", "paying.user@example.com");
params.put("source", "tok_visa");
Customer customer = Customer.create(params);
```

2) Make token:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("customer", customer.getId());
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount("{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}").build();
Token token = Token.create(params, requestOptions);`
```

3) Creating charge:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("amount", 1000);
params.put("currency", "usd");
params.put("source", token.getId());
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount("{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}").build();
Charge charge = Charge.create(params, requestOptions);`
```

Charge created successfully.
But what I try to get list of all charges for this customer, I receive nothing:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("customer", customer.getId());
Charge.list(params); //no charges in response
```

So how to get all charges for this customer that was created in such way?

Comment: Do you save the result in a `ChargeCollection`? Like `ChargeCollection collection = Charge.list(params, requestOptions);`.

Comment: Of course I save it... But it contain no charges...

Comment: Have you tried `params.get(customer.getId())`?

Comment: How do you iterate over the collection and exactly what output do you get? Does it give you any warning or an error?

Comment: "object": "list",
  "data": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "total_count": null,
  "url": "/v1/charges",
  "count": null,
  "request_options": {
    "api_key": "{STRIPE_API_KEY}",
    "client_id": null,
    "stripe_version": "2017-08-15",
    "idempotency_key": null,
    "stripe_account": null,
    "connect_timeout": 30000,
    "read_timeout": 80000
  },
  "request_params": {
    "customer": "{CUSTOMER_ID}"
  }
}

Comment: Are you sure that you create it successfully? I've checked the source code of the API, and it either you give it wrong `params` and/or `requestOptions`, or it's empty because there's nothing in it.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I created it cuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to list charges that were created on the connected account.  Meaning, you need to pass along the same request options you used to create the charge.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount("{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}").build();
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("customer", customer.getId());
Charge.list(params, requestOptions); //no charges in response
```

Comment: In this case I get "No such customer" error. (Because there is no such customer on the connected account. It's on my account)